# CMake set linker option to /DEBUG:FULL in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am using CMake to generate a Visual Studio 2017 project for C++. I am trying to change the CMake to set the linker option to /DEBUG:FULL as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=vs-2019). The default in Visual Studio 2017 is /DEBUG:FASTLINK.
The Microsoft docs says to go to Property Pages->Linker->Debugging->Generate Full Program Database File. But my property pages look like this with no Linker Options. 
[property pages](https://i.gyazo.com/b2d52c3688e396b984b3ed6a448390dd.png)

My ultimate goal is to get the CMake to generate the Visual Studio project with the linker option set to /DEBUG:FULL. But I also can't find where that setting is in the Visual Studio project. I am guessing that I use set_target_properties() in the CMake for my library with some property that changes the linker option to /DEBUG:FULL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your project properties are different because the project is a static library. Those settings are available for executables (.exe file or DLL).

With cmake you can use [`target_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/target_link_options.html).

Comment: I tried adding this command but it doesn't seem to do anything. 
target_link_options(Transformer PRIVATE "LINKER:/DEBUG:FULL")
The documentation is not clear to me what linker options I can use.

Comment: *LINKER:* is the portable way, just do "/DEBUG:FULL"